# What is safe mode?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-desire, reboot, safe-mode

My USC "Desire" locked up the other day. I have Android 2.2 installed. It just kept rebooting to the splash screen over and over and over again. Being an old Mac user I thought some "key command" might get it to stop.  So I tried holding the HOME key as it booted, brought it to "safe mode". Ane more reboot 
and it was running again.

Is there a log I can look at to see what the issue may have been? What else can one do in "safe mode"?

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure about logging but, safe mode disables many system services during boot. On some systems it can bypass the security pattern or pin. I haven't found any additional features. It seems to be more for reducing features for the sake of diagnostics. Windows has a similar feature.

I've posted a link on starting safe mode on a variety of devices for others to use; however, it probably won't show up until I gain a bit of rep.

[Safe mode for Android](https://web.archive.org/web/20180904223223/http://androinica.com/2010/08/how-to-activate-android%E2%80%99s-safe-mode-to-get-out-of-a-force-close-loop/)

Comment: Not only system services -- all user apps as well. Think of it like "safe mode" in Firefox temporarily disables all installed addons.

Comment: He is already started into safe mode, why do you think telling him how to get where he is is an answer to the question?

Comment: Usually, Safe Mode is an interface to solve issues. IDK about I OS, but in "*inux" W10.

Answer (score 1):

Found this in a Sony Xperia manual:

> Safe Mode temporarily disables all applications that have been
>   installed via the Android Market. Performing this troubleshooting step
>   is necessary to determine whether a 3rd party application is the cause
>   of an Operating System / Application issue. Safe Mode should always be
>   performed prior to a hard (factory) reset.

The safe mode is there to provide repair in case one of the applications causes the phone to behave strangely or misbehave.

The phone has to be rebooted into safe mode, which can be done by pressing the power button and holding one of the keys.

The second key in some phones:

```
 - volume down/up button
 - menu button
 - home button
 - back button
 - other type of button
```

When you enter safe mode there is a label "Safe Mode" at the bottom of the screen (left or right corner).

In some phones the debugging menu has more options in safe mode, all related to application management.

Comment: You should really get / find the manual for your phone.  It will have specifics to Android 2.2, (lowliest of the lows).  Yes, you are close remembering those old Mac OS 7/8/9 key commands!  The manipulations for the proper menu are similar.  I'll restate, each phone carrier has their own version (in this case 2.2) of OS.  Then there are the hardware specifics again can differ between carriers.  (I'll stop now before a BetaMax/VHS discussion comes out)