# dexopt produces a segmentation fault preventing boot-up

Tags: stock-android

I built an application for Android (non-rooted) and tried to install it on my 'phone (Sony Xperia E), but when my 'phone tries to run dexopt on it, dexopt segfaults.

To make matters worse, I rebooted, and now it won't boot up until it's succeeded at the dexopt, so I can't use my device.  Here's a log of the segfault:

```
I/PackageManager(  399): Running dexopt on: ip7.bathuniapp
E/Adreno200-EGL(  392): <qeglDrvAPI_eglTerminate:2531>: <<<< Reset Blob Cache Funcs >>>>
W/dalvikvm(  487): Invalid file flags in class Lgroovy/ui/OutputTransforms$ObjectHolder_localTransforms;: 0002
F/libc    (  487): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 487 (dexopt)
I/DEBUG   (  157): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  157): Build fingerprint: 'Sony/C1505_1270-4432/C1505:4.1.1/11.3.A.2.23/20130731.052941:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  157): pid: 487, tid: 487, name: dexopt  >>> /system/bin/dexopt <<<
I/DEBUG   (  157): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000004
I/DEBUG   (  157):     r0 41ac8d98  r1 00000000  r2 a1cbfd84  r3 a1cbfd84
I/DEBUG   (  157):     r4 00000000  r5 41ac8d98  r6 44824fac  r7 00000008
I/DEBUG   (  157):     r8 00000001  r9 00000004  sl 4016d5b8  fp 1dcd64ff
I/DEBUG   (  157):     ip 40072f80  sp bed27978  lr 4012b27b  pc 4011481c  cpsr 60000030
I/DEBUG   (  157):     d0  72546c61636f6c5f  d1  736d726f66736e61
I/DEBUG   (  157):     d2  656a624f24736d72  d3  7265646c6f487463
I/DEBUG   (  157):     d4  42b6ebc842b6eb90  d5  42b6ec3842b6ec00
I/DEBUG   (  157):     d6  42b6eca842b6ec70  d7  42b6ed1842b6ece0
I/DEBUG   (  157):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  157):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  157):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  157):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  157):     d16 42b6ed8842b6ed50  d17 42b6edf842b6edc0
I/DEBUG   (  157):     d18 42b6ee6842b6ee30  d19 42b6eed842b6eea0
I/DEBUG   (  157):     d20 42b6ef4842b6ef10  d21 42b6efb842b6ef80
I/DEBUG   (  157):     d22 42b6f02842b6eff0  d23 42b6f09842b6f060
I/DEBUG   (  157):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  157):     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  157):     d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  157):     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  157):     scr 00000010
I/DEBUG   (  157): 
I/DEBUG   (  157): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  157):     #00  pc 0005281c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmLockObject+23)
I/DEBUG   (  157):     #01  pc 00069277  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  157):     #02  pc 0005a549  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  157):     #03  pc 0005aa41  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmContinueOptimization(int, long, long, char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool)+240)
I/DEBUG   (  157):     #04  pc 00000c8d  /system/bin/dexopt
I/DEBUG   (  157): 
I/DEBUG   (  157): stack:
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27938  41b24198  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed2793c  00001000  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27940  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27944  00000028  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27948  41acd548  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed2794c  40168c60  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27950  00000005  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27954  41b05fc8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27958  42b65260  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed2795c  00000005  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27960  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27964  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27968  4016d5b8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed2796c  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27970  df0027ad  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27974  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  157):     #00  bed27978  41ac8d98  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed2797c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27980  a1cbfd84  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27984  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27988  41ac8d98  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed2798c  44824fac  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@ip7.bathuniapp-1.apk@classes.dex
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27990  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27994  44d5cd90  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@ip7.bathuniapp-1.apk@classes.dex
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27998  44d5cd90  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@ip7.bathuniapp-1.apk@classes.dex
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed2799c  4016d5b8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed279a0  00032026  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed279a4  4012b27b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  157):     #01  bed279a8  00000002  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed279ac  41ae5f88  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed279b0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed279b4  a1cbfd84  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed279b8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed279bc  41ac8d98  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed279c0  41ac8d98  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed279c4  447848cc  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@ip7.bathuniapp-1.apk@classes.dex
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed279c8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed279cc  40168c60  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed279d0  41ad2578  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed279d4  00001417  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed279d8  00000002  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed279dc  4016d5b8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed279e0  4015d134  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed279e4  4488631f  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@ip7.bathuniapp-1.apk@classes.dex
I/DEBUG   (  157):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (  157):     #02  bed27a38  00040000  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27a3c  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27a40  0000b30b  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27a44  4016d5b8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27a48  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27a4c  4093d000  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-aux-structure (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27a50  007de220  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27a54  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27a58  00000005  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27a5c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27a60  4472f000  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@ip7.bathuniapp-1.apk@classes.dex
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27a64  4016d5b8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27a68  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27a6c  4472f028  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@ip7.bathuniapp-1.apk@classes.dex
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27a70  007de220  
I/DEBUG   (  157):          bed27a74  4011ca45  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmContinueOptimization(int, long, long, char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool)+244)
I/DEBUG   (  157): 
I/DEBUG   (  157): memory near r0:
I/DEBUG   (  157):     41ac8d78 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157):     41ac8d88 00000000 00000000 c4bbc1b1 00000453  ............S...
I/DEBUG   (  157):     41ac8d98 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157):     41ac8da8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157):     41ac8db8 00000000 00000001 00000000 400e14c0  ...............@
I/DEBUG   (  157): 
I/DEBUG   (  157): memory near r2:
I/DEBUG   (  157):     a1cbfd64 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157):     a1cbfd74 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157):     a1cbfd84 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157):     a1cbfd94 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157):     a1cbfda4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157): 
I/DEBUG   (  157): memory near r3:
I/DEBUG   (  157):     a1cbfd64 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157):     a1cbfd74 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157):     a1cbfd84 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157):     a1cbfd94 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157):     a1cbfda4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157): 
I/DEBUG   (  157): memory near r5:
I/DEBUG   (  157):     41ac8d78 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157):     41ac8d88 00000000 00000000 c4bbc1b1 00000453  ............S...
I/DEBUG   (  157):     41ac8d98 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157):     41ac8da8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157):     41ac8db8 00000000 00000001 00000000 400e14c0  ...............@
I/DEBUG   (  157): 
I/DEBUG   (  157): memory near r6:
I/DEBUG   (  157):     44824f8c 00000733 00000001 00000abe 0011386c  3...........l8..
I/DEBUG   (  157):     44824f9c 000019a7 00000000 001571b5 00000000  .........q......
I/DEBUG   (  157):     44824fac 00000734 00000002 00000abe 0011386c  4...........l8..
I/DEBUG   (  157):     44824fbc 00003eac 007d33c0 001572f3 00000000  .>...3}..r......
I/DEBUG   (  157):     44824fcc 0000073a 00000001 00000abe 0011386c  :...........l8..
I/DEBUG   (  157): 
I/DEBUG   (  157): memory near sl:
I/DEBUG   (  157):     4016d598 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157):     4016d5a8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157):     4016d5b8 41ac6b18 41ac6b08 00200000 01000000  .k.A.k.A.. .....
I/DEBUG   (  157):     4016d5c8 01000000 00004000 00004000 00000000  .....@...@......
I/DEBUG   (  157):     4016d5d8 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157): 
I/DEBUG   (  157): memory near fp:
I/DEBUG   (  157):     1dcd64dc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157):     1dcd64ec ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157):     1dcd64fc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157):     1dcd650c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157):     1dcd651c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I/DEBUG   (  157): 
I/DEBUG   (  157): memory near ip:
I/DEBUG   (  157):     40072f60 00000000 00000000 00000000 40352185  .............!5@
I/DEBUG   (  157):     40072f70 403452b0 4034c90d 4033fa0c 403456b0  .R4@..4@..3@.V4@
I/DEBUG   (  157):     40072f80 4033fbc0 40346959 40340104 40341560  ..3@Yi4@..4@`.4@
I/DEBUG   (  157):     40072f90 4036cb5d 4034a11c 40351dcd 4035d745  ].6@..4@..5@E.5@
I/DEBUG   (  157):     40072fa0 4034f5ad 40341468 40340c00 403411a0  ..4@h.4@..4@..4@
I/DEBUG   (  157): 
I/DEBUG   (  157): memory near sp:
I/DEBUG   (  157):     bed27958 42b65260 00000005 00000001 00000000  `R.B............
I/DEBUG   (  157):     bed27968 4016d5b8 00000001 df0027ad 00000000  ...@.....'......
I/DEBUG   (  157):     bed27978 41ac8d98 00000000 a1cbfd84 00000000  ...A............
I/DEBUG   (  157):     bed27988 41ac8d98 44824fac 00000000 44d5cd90  ...A.O.D.......D
I/DEBUG   (  157):     bed27998 44d5cd90 4016d5b8 00032026 4012b27b  ...D...@& ..{..@
I/DEBUG   (  157): 
I/DEBUG   (  157): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   (  157):     401147fc 3b9ac9ff c4653600 4ff7e92d 0904f101  ...;.6e.-..O....
I/DEBUG   (  157):     4011480c 8024f8d0 f8df4605 460cb0bc 07c8ea4f  ..$..F.....FO...
I/DEBUG   (  157):     4011481c f0106860 d14b0601 03cff3c0 d1094543  `h....K.....CE..
I/DEBUG   (  157):     4011482c f6416860 f50072ff 60632300 4fd3ebb2  `hA..r...#c`...O
I/DEBUG   (  157):     4011483c e038d144 ea40b94b 464a0107 e912f7cc  D.8.K.@...JF....
I/DEBUG   (  157): 
I/DEBUG   (  157): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   (  157):     4012b258 b1576c6f f0002c00 462080d6 f9a4f7fe  olW..,.... F....
I/DEBUG   (  157):     4012b268 21004620 ff5af7eb 4628e0cd f7e94621   F.!..Z...(F!F..
I/DEBUG   (  157):     4012b278 6a6efac5 63664620 fc6ef7fe b9984606  ..nj Ffc..n..F..
I/DEBUG   (  157):     4012b288 63604621 f7e94628 4620fb21 f98cf7fe  !F`c(F..!. F....
I/DEBUG   (  157):     4012b298 46314620 f7eb2601 4640ff41 22019908   F1F.&..A.@F..."
I/DEBUG   (  157): crash_level = -1
I/DEBUG   (  490): debuggerd: Jul 31 2013 05:41:06
```

Comment: Apologies for the stupid tags — I don't have enough reputation to create new ones.

Comment: `dexopt` is not at fault here - `ip7.bathuniapp` what is this app? That is inducing the fault.

Comment: Yes, but surely an app shouldn't be able to break the device like this.

Comment: I cannot help but notice further down the stack trace, the data cache for the app seems corrupted which chokes on the dexopt and throws a wobbler. Have you tried clearing/resetting the dalvik cache?

Comment: Everything I've seen says that I need root to do this — like the comment says, my device is not rooted.

Comment: One or two questions - what version of Android, also you mentioned you built an application, is this your application `groovy/ui/OutputTransforms$ObjectHolder_localTransforms;` or part of one of your classes?

Comment: 4.1, and groovy was one of the libraries used. BathUniApp was my application.

Comment: Ahhhh..... I suspected that! Did you not consider that somewhere in your code is faulty... ? Did you check around for support/bug tracking on groovy itself? This is bordering on off-topic now that the headline of the question was bit sensationalised when it turns out your app is causing dexopt to throw a wobbler. Looking at our sister site [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914010/is-groovy-a-potential-development-language-for-android) on the topic of Groovy, it is best you get in touch with groovy contributors to find out why!

Comment: Also, this caught my eye - [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GSoC+2013) in particular this, and I quote *Currently, Groovy is not able to run properly on Google's Android mobile platform out of the box.*

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't the one to write that code, that was my teammate. I'm just trying to get my phone to work again. It's a bit late for code-checking now.

Comment: Try booting into Android Safe Mode? [See this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8258/what-is-safe-mode)

Comment: Tried about half a dozen different ways, it just keeps going back to 'android is updating...' screen.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you found a null pointer dereference in `dexopt`. You should report this on the official Android bug tracker, though you may find it's already fixed in a newer version.

As for your immediate problem, you might have to boot into recovery and do a factory-reset from there.

Comment: I would try removing the offending app first before nuking all data with a factory reset.

Comment: I can't boot into recovery. Can I do a factory-reset from the shell?

Comment: @MLev. What's preventing you from booting into recovery? Have you tried [these steps](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/sony-xperia-e-recovery-mode/)?

Comment: @Dan your answer is incorrect, the offending app seems to cause problems!

Comment: @Chahk, 1) the LED never changes colour — it goes straight into the problematic optimization without ever turning the LED on.  2) adb reboot recovery also boots straight into the optimization.  3) I can't run the QuickBoot app because the device doesn't boot up.